# Unwanted Spacing / Image Resizing in C# WPF StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, image-resizing, stackpanel

Hopefully this one is simple - however, I can't find any posts that quite relate.

I'm building a horizontal StackPanel with images, and for some reason ONE of the images keeps getting resized slightly, causing a very unwanted border around the image. Is there anything I can do to FORCE the output to be the image's original pixel size, or is there something I can disable that is allowing this StackPanel to resize my image ever so slightly?

[image: You can see the border causing gaps right after the Title text]

If you look closely, you can see the transparent border happening right around the image that ends the title text. I have no clue why this is happening. Here is the code for the image:

```
Image titleRightCap = new Image();
        titleRightCap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/skins/default/top_r_title_cap.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        borderTop.Children.Add(titleRightCap);
        titleRightCap.Loaded += delegate (object s, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            headWidth += titleRightCap.ActualWidth;
        };
```

Here is the Live output where you can see the size difference occurring:

[image: Live Output]

I feel like this should get fixed if I can force the size to remain constant, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You will get to know the exact problem only by looking into the *Visual Tree*.

Comment: Well, the last screenshot is from the Live Visual Tree. All of the properties match every other image I'm using in this scenario, and this is the only one scaling like this. The image editor confirms it is exactly 38x10, but the compiler keeps shrinking it to the 'ActualHeight' and 'ActualWidth' seen above. I can't find anything in the tree that explains this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure *why* this was happening. However, it seems that it is in regards to some sort of internal math calculation.

This item is a "top" border control that is dynamically-generated and expands when windows change sizes. In order to dynamically expand, there is a grid element with an imagebrush which just paints the background of the border to fill. However, this requires the width of all other elements in the border control to calculate properly.

The Title element is a dynamically-generated label which sizes to the text. Unfortunately, this can be any width double, and makes the math go nuts for the dynamic grid that fills for the stretch.

In whatever way the StackPanel interpretes these size changes it was for some reason changing the size of this Image to compensate the width to reach exactly 100% width.

So, what I did to fix this was take the Width value of my dynamically-generated Title label and round the value to the next nearest whole number:

```
titleTextGraphic.Width = Math.Ceiling(titleTextGraphic.ActualWidth);
```

Now the element marked with a dynamically-scaling width should change. When ran, my border now no longer has a gap.

[image]

So, this seems to be working fine for now. I appreciate the help given and hope that this helps with anyone else encountering similar issues.